# Getting error in ansible tower awx while using regex_findall filter

Tags: regex, ansible, ansible-awx

Getting below error while i am running my playbook in ansible tower awx, in my code i have regex_findall

```
   - set_fact:
         spool_ip_address: "{{output.stdout_lines|regex_findall('\\d+.\\d+.\\d+.\\d+')}}"
```

error while running in ansible tower AWX:

```
{
    "msg": "Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({{output.stdout_lines|regex_findall('\\\\d+.\\\\d+.\\\\d+.\\\\d+')}}): expected string or bytes-like object",
    "_ansible_no_log": false
}
```

where as i don't get above error when i ran from my laptop. i have ansible version 2.10, i do get list of all ip address from `output.stdout_lines` like
`spool_ip_address: [10.10.20.100,20.30.40.50,100.100.200.1]`

ansible awx is running Ansible 2.9.14 with awx version : AWX 15.0.1

Comment: Replace `output.stdout_lines` with `output.stdout` and escape literal dots in the regex pattern.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew still same error from AWX
`"Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({{output.stdout|regex_findall('\\\\d+.\\\\d+.\\\\d+.\\\\d+')}}): expected string or bytes-like object"`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Stribiżew

no luck `output.stdout|regex_findall('\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+'` , i didn't understand why do  i  see four escape like `\\\\`
`Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({{output.stdout|regex_findall('\\\\d+\\\\.\\\\d+\\\\.\\\\d+\\\\.\\\\d+')}}): expected string or bytes-like object`